# Why doesn't `git cherry-pick` (without `--no-commit`) run my post-commit hook?

Tags: git, githooks, git-cherry-pick, post-commit-hook

How can I trigger a post-commit hook with the command `git cherry-pick <commit>`?

What I've tried:

- I tried the command `git commit -m '...'` . It triggered the post-commit hook normally.
- In the githooks document, there are no hooks related to cherry-pick.
- After viewing the source code of Git, I found it uses `git merge` in some cases, and `git commit` in others. But I'm not sure when to use which command.

My questions are:

1. Why don't post-commit hooks work when I use `git cherry-pick`?
2. Is there a hook that cherry-pick will run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why don't post-commit hooks work when I use `git cherry-pick`?

The `post-commit` hook is run after creating a commit.

However, cherry-pick does not really create a new commit with new information (from the user perspective) but copies another commit.

> Is there a hook that cherry-pick will run?

Yes, the [prepare-commit-msg](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg) should be run before commit is cherry-picked, even though the `commit-msg` hook is not executed.

Comment: Thanks, I want to check the file that has been commited by `git cherry-pick`, like the `post-commit` hook, it need to run after the entire commit process is completed. 
Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: You could try to check if the file is staged. If it is staged, it will be committed.

Comment: It can solve my problem. I truly appreciate your timely help!